# Fastest Way of Using Coordinates as Keys in Javascript Hashmap

Tags: javascript, performance, hashmap, hashtable

I'd like to store objects using their coordinates, like so:

```
var hash_map = {};
hash_map[x + "-" + y] = new Object();
```

These can then be retrieved using `hash_map[x + "-" + y]`.

However, I am not sure about whether creating a new string every time an object is accessed is such a great idea.

An alternative would be to combine the coordinates by doing something like `x | (y >>> 16)` but I have no idea about how many bits to shift the `y` value by, what actually happens internally (since javascript's numbers are all floats, so there's an exponent and mantissa etc) and whether it's actually worth it.

**tl;dr What's the fastest way (including garbage collection) of storing objects in a hash map with coordinates as keys?**

Comment: Part of that I can answer ... JavaScript bitwise operators all work on 16-bit integers

Comment: Do you have to use a hash map? Assuming the coordinates are integers, why not use a 2D array? Or even a 2D hash map. If you used arrays, you could pre-allocate the keys and save yourself the cost of adding unique keys every time a new location is encountered.

Comment: What is the maximum size of the coordinates? What type of coordinate is it (GPS coordinates, grid coordinates, etc.)?

Comment: what do you need that for? I can't think of a situation where I would need/use this structure *(to cache the Points by position)*? If I need to store points by their position I'd probably use a quad-tree.

Comment: @MikeC, you're right! I could use an array. In context, it's for 2D game chucks, of which random ones need to be loaded, so the array would be wasting a bit of space though

Comment: @Thomas it's for 2D game chunks that I'd like to retrieve using coordinates

Comment: @10100111001 they're grid coordinates and the maximum size could be as low as 16k.

Comment: @Lolums, 16000 what? columns/rows? cells? pixel per axis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below solution to compound a pair of coordinates into a single 32 bit signed integer. This integer can then be used as the key for a JS object. The 2 coordinates can only be a maximum of 16 bits. Therefore x and y can only contains values -32767 to +32767 (2^15-1).

In the below example, 100 random pair of coordinates are generated and added to to the hash_map object with their values containing the x and y coordinates calculated from the key. The coordinates must be within the aforementioned range otherwise an exception will be thrown.

```js
var MAX_16BIT_SIGNED = 32767; //Math.floor((Math.pow(2, 16)/2)-1);

function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getRandomKey() {
  var x = getRandomIntInclusive(MAX_16BIT_SIGNED * -1, MAX_16BIT_SIGNED),
    y = getRandomIntInclusive(MAX_16BIT_SIGNED * -1, MAX_16BIT_SIGNED);

  //console.log("Generated key with x: " + x + " and y: " + y);
  return getKey(x, y);
}

function getKey(x, y) {
  if (x > MAX_16BIT_SIGNED || y > MAX_16BIT_SIGNED)
    throw "Invalid X or Y value.";
  x += MAX_16BIT_SIGNED;
  y += MAX_16BIT_SIGNED;
  return (x << 16) | y;
}

function getX(key) {
  return (key >> 16) - MAX_16BIT_SIGNED;
}

function getY(key) {
  return (key & 0xFFFF) - MAX_16BIT_SIGNED;
}

var hash_map = {};
hash_map[getKey(MAX_16BIT_SIGNED * -1, MAX_16BIT_SIGNED)] = "test";
hash_map[getKey(MAX_16BIT_SIGNED, MAX_16BIT_SIGNED)] = "test";
hash_map[getKey(MAX_16BIT_SIGNED * -1, MAX_16BIT_SIGNED * -1)] = "test";
hash_map[getKey(MAX_16BIT_SIGNED, MAX_16BIT_SIGNED * -1)] = "test";
//hash_map[getKey(MAX_16BIT_SIGNED+1, MAX_16BIT_SIGNED+1)] = "test";

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var key = getRandomKey();
  hash_map[key] = {
    x: getX(key),
    y: getY(key)
  };
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(hash_map));
console.log(100 === Object.keys(hash_map).length);
```